# Is there a way to connect Microsoft TFS to Amazon RDS using SQL Auth?

Tags: sql-server, tfs, amazon-rds

Our on-prem TFS solution has been moved to an AWS EC2 instance. The database it was pointing to was an on-prem Microsoft SQL Server instance. I've backed up the on-prem DB and restored into AWS RDS - however, am facing an issue connecting to the RDS instance without a Windows Auth user. Does TFS not allow SQL Auth at all, and only Windows auth?

Comment: Hi Helene,  any update on this issue? Did you get a chance to implement the solution that I suggested? Were you able to resolve?

Comment: Hi there. I had to stand up an EC2 instance with SQL on it and join it to the same domain as the TFS server in order to get Windows auth to work; it seems RDS is not a choice at all with TFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, it's not support with SQL Authentication at present.

On premise TFS **only supports Windows auth** (either local or domain).

You could take a look at *Vladimir Khvostov MSFT*'s response in this similar question: [Trying to use AWS RDS (relational database service) for back-end SQL Server database for TFS, won't connect](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6c9886f9-2bf1-45ed-8ad2-bea22b65f1f3/trying-to-use-aws-rds-relational-database-service-for-backend-sql-server-database-for-tfs-wont?forum=tfsgeneral)

Besides, in case you need, you could also take a look at [requirements for Azure DevOps/TFS on-premises](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/requirements?view=azure-devops).